# Eliminar doble comillas en archivo csv en java

Tags: java, java-8, opencsv

**Contexto de la aplicacion**

Estoy realizando un programa en java que me genera un archivo csv, para el cual utilizo la librería opencsv, para llenar el archivo obtengo los datos desde una base de datos con una simple consulta, para esto hago una conversión a aun array string para el guardado de los datos, todo bien hasta allí.

**Problema**

El problema que se tiene es que al momento de agregar en el archivo los datos, esto me los agrega con una "" despues del primer elemento, ejemplo:

```
abcd,"abcd","abcd","abcd","abcd","abcd","abcd","abcd","abcd"
```

Como ven el primer elemento lo guarda normal sin las "" pero el resto lo guarda asi, y pues con ese archivo se van a utilizar una serie consultas posterior y al contra con esas "" puede generar problemas.

**Solución implementada**

De esta manera es que implemento todo, primero verifico si el archivo exite y lo creo de lo contrario:

```
    boolean existe = new File("./src/main/java/recurso/base_datos.csv").exists();

    File fichero = new File("./src/main/java/recurso","base_datos.csv");
    CSVWriter escritura;
    if(!existe){
        if(fichero.createNewFile()){
            escritura = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(fichero));
            List<String[]> data = toArrayString(lista);
            escritura.writeAll(data);
            escritura.close();
        }
    }else{
        escritura = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(fichero));
        List<String[]> data = toArrayString(lista);
        escritura.writeAll(data);
        escritura.close();
    }
```

Y de esta forma convierto lo que traigo desde la base de datos para guardar en el archivo:

```
private static List<String[]> toArrayString(List<Serie> lista){
    List<String[]> records = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    //Cabecera del archivo
    records.add(new String[]{"Title","Year","Rated","Released","Season" });
    Iterator<Serie> it = lista.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        Sondeo s = it.next();
        records.add(new String[] { s.getTitle(),s.getYear(),s.getRated(),s.getReleased(),s.getSeason() });
    }
    return records;
}
```

Pues no se si los archivos csv también manejan eso con "" pero e vistos algunos y no lo traen, alguien podría decir que estoy haciendo mal o como solucionar eso.

Comment: Trata de usar el método ```replace``` para remplazar por nada, así los tendrás sin comillas

Comment: Como? disculpa, entiendo que el replace y el replaceAll mediante una expresion regular lo permite, pero ¿como y donde crees que es viable la implementación?

Comment: no estarás probando a abrir los csv con excel, verdad?